# Как сохранять сразу два файла, используя поле ArrayField?

Tags: django, файловая-система

Стоит задача: сохранить два изображения. Надо чтобы в это поле записывалось два пути к разным файлам. Вот как это должно работать со стороны пользователя. Пользователь загружает изображение в админке, оно загружается нормально и вместе с этим автоматически, не заменяя загруженное изображение, загружается второй файл(изображение с уменьшенным разрешением). Пользователь загружает картинку с разрешением 1000х600(или больше), а код меняет его на 250х300, как изменить разрешение, я знаю, но как это все реализовать нет. Возможно для этого нужен сигнал(Django Model Signals), но я не понимаю, как правильно его написать.
Предположим что модель такая:

```
class News(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(Или ArrayField)(upload_to='news')
```

Comment: Кажется, я уже видел подобный вопрос, но решения вроде не было. Но если у вас всегда ровно два файла, то стоит вместо ArrayField сделать два отдельных поля

Comment: Не всегда есть два файла вроде.